# What'll we get as the compilation result?

Tags: java, compilation

This is some snippets

```
  public class Overload {
      public void method(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
      }
      public void method(java.io.FileNotFoundException f) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
      }
      public void method(java.io.IOException i) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
      }
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        Overload test = new Overload();
        test.method(null);
      }
    }
```

This is simple code .What will we get as the compilation result?

Comment: why don't you compile and see for yourself?

Comment: Well compile and run it!

Comment: You will get FileNotFoundException

Comment: Do you not have a Java compiler? Otherwise, I don't see why you can't simply do it yourself; why are you asking us to do it?

Comment: Try browxy.com to have online compiler to run your code

Answer (score 3):

This program will print out "FileNotFoundException".

This is due to the way polymorphic methods work in Java.  `test.method(null)` is an ambiguous method call because any of the three implementations could be used.  When multiple signatures are suitable for a given parameter, the most specific sub-class will be chosen.

In this case that is `FileNotFoundException` because the inheritance hierarchy looks like this:

```
System.Object
  System.Exception
    System.SystemException
      System.IO.IOException
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

In general, programmers should be aware of this behavior but should not try to leverage it.  This kind of code can be very confusing and often leads to unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You get FileNotFoundException

but yes you can just run it and see by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be "Object"

Null isn't an object I know but I suspect the Object o arg would get set to null.

Comment: Just tried it and you do get a FileNotFoundException. I love someone to explain why